# Nested Algorithms Markup with IEEEtran

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algpseudocode

I'am using the `IEEEtran` class when writing an article and I want to include an algorithm with some (multiple-)nested functions. Including the algorithm in the `IEEEtran` class was confusing at first but I have found two examples that work, however, I can't seem to get them to work on nested functions.

My first approach was the following:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Step 1: Create M (number of samples) Transition Matrices
\ForAll {t}
    \ForAll {a\in A}\\
        \ForAll {i\in\{1,...,n \}}
            Sample M vectors for the i^{th} row of the transition matrix
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\State Step 2: Generate estimates of the value function
\While{j\leq M}
    \State Calculate the value function based on the $j^{th}$ sample
\EndWhile
 \State Step 3: Determine the average value function and the corresponding value function sensitivity
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}
```

However, this worked out this way:

[image: Snapshot of the Result]

I have tried every possible combination of `\\` and `\State`, but I can't figure out what is going on. I mean, there is even an extra **for all** in the text, why?

So, alternatively, I tried to use the `algorithm2e` package with a work-around for the `IEEEtran` class but that does not seem to allow nested structures at all.

I would be very much appreciated is someone would help me understand what is happening.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](//tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you're using math content that is not set in math mode `$`...`$`. After using the appropriate notation, your example code works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \raggedright
  \State Step 1: Create $M$ (number of samples) Transition Matrices
  \ForAll { $t$ }
    \ForAll { $a \in A$ }
      \ForAll { $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ }
        \State Sample $M$ vectors for the $i$\textsuperscript{th} row of the
        \State \quad transition matrix%
          \strut}
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
  \State Step 2: Generate estimates of the value function
  \While{ $j \leq M$ }
    \State Calculate the value function based on the $j$\textsuperscript{th} sample
  \EndWhile
  \State Step 3: Determine the average value function and the corresponding value function sensitivity
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

I've added some formatting suggestions (like `\raggedright`), including using a forced break and indent (`\quad`) around the multi-line statement.

Since the `conference` template of [`ieeetran`](//ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) necessarily sets a document in `two-column` mode, there is no need to place the `algorithmic` environment inside a `figure`, as it won't float. However, there may be a need for that, depending on your document layout; `algorithmic` acts like a list and can allow the algorithm to break across the column boundary.

Comment: Thanks! Basic mistake, but sometimes these are the most difficult to see. And I have adopted the formatting suggestions as well

Answer (score 0):

I take it the problem has to do with switching from algorithms to algorithmics since IEEEtran does not support the algorithm float type.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Step 1: Create $M$ (number of samples) Transition Matrices
\ForAll {$t$}
    \ForAll {$a\in A$}
        \ForAll {$i\in\{1,...,n \}$}
            \State Sample $M$ vectors for the $i^{th}$ row of the transition matrix
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\State Step 2: Generate estimates of the value function
\While{$j\leq M$}
    \State Calculate the value function based on the $j^{th}$ sample
\EndWhile
 \State Step 3: Determine the average value function and the corresponding value function sensitivity
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version shows how to indent the entire `\State`.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Step 1: Create $M$ (number of samples) Transition Matrices
\ForAll {$t$}
    \ForAll {$a\in A$}
        \ForAll {$i\in\{1,...,n \}$}
            \State \parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\csname ALG@tlm\endcsname}%
            {\strut Sample $M$ vectors for the $i^{th}$ row of the transition matrix\strut}
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
\EndFor
\State Step 2: Generate estimates of the value function
\While{$j\leq M$}
    \State Calculate the value function based on the $j^{th}$ sample
\EndWhile
 \State Step 3: Determine the average value function and the corresponding value function sensitivity
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]